# Password policy regex

Tags: regex, validation

I've seen quite a few regular expressions regarding password policies, but none of them seem to be working for me. First, here are my requirements:

1. Minimum 8 characters
2. Maximum 40 characters
3. At least one number

I've tried a couple different expressions (see below), and they both work for all my requirements except for #2. It seems no matter what, I can never get a regex that actually validates the max length. Here are the two expressions I have tried:

1. `^.*(?=.{8,40})(?=.*\d).*$`
2. `(?=.{8,40})(?=.*[0-9]).*`

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. Many ways to do it..

```
 ^(?=.{8,40}$).*\d.*$
```

Answer (score 0):

For your requirements you can use this regex:

```
^(?=.*?\d).{8,40}$
```

Answer (score 0):

### Why Your Unanchored Expression Doesn't Work

> (?=.{8,40})(?=.*[0-9]).*

This doesn't work because the expression isn't *anchored*. Think of it this way:

```
.{8,40}
```

will match anywhere in your string where you have at least 8 characters, and having *more* than 40 characters simply stops the engine from continuing to match without actually causing the expression to fail.

To have at least 8 characters, but no more than 40, you need to anchor your expression at the start and end of the string. Depending on your regex engine, one (or both) of the following should work to match valid lengths, albeit with slightly different semantics:

- `^.{8,40}$`
- `\A.{8,40}\z`

### Simplify with Multiple Expressions

The search for "one regex to rule them all" complicates life for no good reason. Unless you have a demonstrable performance reason for doing so, you're better off running multiple checks, with or without regular expressions. For example, in Ruby:

```
def valid_password? str
  return false if str.size < 8 or str.size > 40 or str !~ /\d/
  true
end

valid_password? 'abcd1234'
#=> true

valid_password? 'abc'
#=> false

valid_password? 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
#=> false
```